# BitmapFactory.decodeStream and BitmapFactory.decodeFile behaviour with identical image resource

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bitmapfactory, remoteview

I have a strange behaviour by getting Bitmaps with the methods BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Resources res,int id) and BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName). I want to set a bitmap to my appwidget remoteViews, it is an png image with 319x319px and 32kb, for my understanding, it is a very small image that should be handled easily.

Now, what´s happing is, if I put this image inside my drawables folder and want to load the bitmap with BitmapFactory.decodeResource, the app crashs and I get an error-message that the remoteViews exceeds the max bitmap memory usage. 
What I find out is, that there is max memory usage to the following rule (from developer.google.com) :

```
 The total Bitmap memory used by the RemoteViews object cannot exceed that 
 required to fill the screen 1.5 times, ie. 
 (screen width x screen height x 4 x 1.5) bytes.
```

Now to the strange part: If I load the identical image from sd card and decode it with BitmapFactory.decodeFile(), it works. Why is this happening?

The problem I face here is, that I have to set some default images, if no other one is on my folder in sd card. For this, I put them in to my drawables folder. If I scale them down to 119x119px, then it works and I get no error message. But this is very bad quality and looks totally blurred at the widget.

Can anybody explain, what exactly is the difference of the behaviour how the bitmaps are loaded? Is there any automatic scaling function in decodeFile() that is not in decodeResource()?

A part of code or the logcat output is irrelevant, so I don´t post it here, I just can´t understand this behaviour and don´t know how to handle it. Also, I searched a lot about this and read the API, but there is nothing I can find out.

### EDIT

For now I fixed this with calculating the bitmap memory usage with the above formular and check the bitmap size like this:

```
          DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    double width = (double) metrics.widthPixels;
    double height = (double) metrics.heightPixels;

    double maximumUsage = width * height * 4.0 * 1.5;

    double maximumImageSizeFaktor = (maximumUsage / 3) / 1.5 / 4;
    double maximumImageSize = Math.sqrt(maximumImageSizeFaktor);
    int maxSize = (int) maximumImageSize - 10; //just to get sure, minimize it for 10

    return maxSize;
```

Then I know the maximal size for my bitmaps and can downsample or resize it. But this did not answer the strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If BitmapFactory is loading from drawables then it does also some scaling according the device screen. By loading from file that will not happen. If you put your images in assets folder it will not happen either.